# CSS: Div appear below another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML like that:

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='left'>content left</div>
    <div class='right'>content right</div>
</div>
```

Now, In smart phone devices, I want `div` has class is `right` is appeared ahead of class `left`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the original order of the elements, you could do something like this with pure CSS/HTML.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w66EB/) - try re-sizing the window

**HTML**

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='right'>content right</div>
    <div class='left'>content left</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    background:red;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 481px) {
    .left {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
    .right {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

---

If you don't like that method, there is always an alternative where the order of the elements aren't changed. You tagged this with jQuery, so here:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w66EB/2/) - try re-sizing the window

**HTML**

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='left'>content left</div>
    <div class='right'>content right</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 481){  
      $('.right').insertBefore('.left');
    }
    else {
      $('.right').insertAfter('.left');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think your answer is good. I may have to order div again :(. thank you so much.

Comment: @ JoshC : Do think that using Jquery to order div will affect to SEO?

Comment: @happi Nope. In this instance usage of JS/jQuery does not have any affect on SEO whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code below:
Smartphones (portrait and landscape)

```
@media only screen 
        and (min-width : 320px) 
        and (max-width : 480px) {
            .right,
            .left{
                float: left;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can use javascript and if you are able to detect whe the user is on smartphone, you can try something like this

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
  var rightDiv = divs[i].childNodes[1];
  divs[i].removeChild(rightDiv);
  divs[i].insertBefore(divs[i].childNodes[0], rightDiv);

}
```